# .htaccess rewrite rule to replace TLDt

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect any request with this TLD (.it) to this TLD (.com)
for example :

```
http://example.it?i=3
```

to this :

```
http://example.com?i=3
```

How can we do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess of `.ir` domain:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.ir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

try this its work all time

Comment: I need to do redirect just for .ir

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url